# How to force emacs with AUCTeX to show compilation in new buffer

Tags: xetex, auctex

So I am using AUCTeX with xetex in emacs and each time after I compile the file I get a split window showing the compilation process. I don't want to completely hide this since I find it useful for debugging, but I want it to appear in a different buffer and not bother me when there are no errors. Is this possible? Another option, although less great, would be to automatically hide it except when there are compilation errors.

I have the option:

```lisp
(setq TeX-show-compilation t)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution it to hook onto `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel`.  In this way, you can check for the presence of errors after the compiler has finished its job.  Add the following code to your initialization file:

```lisp
(defadvice TeX-LaTeX-sentinel
  (around mg-TeX-LaTeX-sentinel-open-output activate)
  "Open output when there are errors."
  ;; Run `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel' as usual.
  ad-do-it
  ;; Check for the presence of errors.
  (when
      (with-current-buffer TeX-command-buffer
    (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern (TeX-master-file))))
    ;; If there are errors, open the output buffer.
    (TeX-recenter-output-buffer nil)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The *problem* with the compilation step is that the next buffer is extremely large. I typically do this:

```lisp
(defun shrink-window-to-height(height)
  "Shrink window height to certain height."
  (interactive "nNew window height: ")
  (if (> (window-height) height)
    (shrink-window (- (window-height) height))
    (enlarge-window (- height (window-height)))
  )
)

(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("pdfLaTeX" "pdflatex -shell-escape %t" TeX-run-interactive nil t))
(defun do-pdflatex ()
    "pdflatex with shell escape."
    (interactive nil)
    (save-buffer)
    (let ((process (TeX-active-process)))
      (if process
          (TeX-kill-job)))
    (TeX-command "pdfLaTeX" 'TeX-master-file)
    (other-window 1)
    (shrink-window-to-height 7)
    (other-window -1)
    (TeX-recenter-output-buffer nil)
)
(global-set-key [f3] 'do-pdflatex)
```

It does this:

1. Kills any active compilation steps
2. Starts a new compilation step
3. Switch buffer to the compiling window (not exactly, but if 2 buffers are open this will happen)
4. Shrink the window to height 7
5. Switch back to original buffer

As it takes up so little space it usually doesn't bother me when it compiles fine. I have never looked into this, but it probably means hacking into the process to check it its done, which I suspect is not that easy.

Comment: Two issues: `"pdfLaTeX"` is not a built-in AUCTeX command (why not using `"LaTeX"`?); `shrink-window-to-height` function doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer, it has been a long time since I created these scripts! ;) If anything else is missing, please ask!

Comment: I'm getting "Symbol's value as variable is void: TeX-command-list".

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo I suspect you have a legacy AucTeX installation.

Comment: Please correct me: you define `do-pdflatex` but you add "pdflatex" to `TeX-command-list`.  Shouldn't it be `(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("do-pdflatex" ...`? At least to me, your solution is not working.  In my configuration, it splits the frame vertically and runs the compilation in the new buffer.